# How can I fetch value from 3 tables using laravel relationship?

Tags: laravel

I have 4 tables named: `categories`, `products`, `blogs`, `companies`.

```
+-----------+
| Category  |
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Cat1 |
| 2  | Cat2 |
+----+------+

+-----------+
|  Company  |
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|    |      |
+----+------+

+-------------------------+
|         Product         |
+----+-------------+------+
| id | category_id | name |
+----+-------------+------+
| 1  | 1           | P1   |
| 2  | 2           | P2   |
| 3  | 1           | P3   |
+----+-------------+------+

+---------------------------+
|           Blog            |
+----+------------+---------+
| id | product_id | heading |
+----+------------+---------+
| 1  | 1          | H1      |
| 2  | 2          | H3      |
| 3  | 3          | H4      |
+----+------------+---------+
```

Blog Model

```php
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Product Model

```php
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

```php
Blog::with('product.category')
        ->where('status', 'Y')
        ->where('featured_position', 'Y')
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

From the above tables the result will show 2 blogs namely blogs having id 1 and 3. But the above code is fetching result for all the blogs from the blog table.

Comment: Have you tried `where('category_id', 1)`, or `where('categories.id', 1)`?

Comment: @JustCarty i am feelin i am missing somthing , can he do that ? i mean the category has many blogs as he stated

Comment: yes tried but its showing error.

Comment: @Abhishek What error is it showing? You're being really vague. Show us the error, or change `get()` to `toSql()` and show us what that produces too.

Comment: @Abhishek can you tell me what king of relationship between category and blog ? plus did you try the one below ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to query the relationship.

```php
$categoryId = 1;
$productQuery = function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
    // This $query object will be for the Product models, so we can treat it as
    // such.
    // We can query like we would on a Product, like Product::where([...]).
    $query->with('category')->where('category_id', $categoryId);
};
$blogs = Blog::whereHas('product', $productQuery)
->with(['product' => $productQuery])
->get();
```

I've set the category ID to a variable, in case you need to change it during runtime.

Also, note that the `with` is completely optional.
If you exclude it, your query will run exactly the same, just without [constrained eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). The effects of this are just that you will have to perform more database requests. The benefits come if you never actually need the relationship, then it won't have been fetch unnecessarily.

If you're curious what the SQL command will be, it will be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `blogs`
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `products`
    WHERE `blogs`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` AND `category_id` = ?
)
```

In simple terms, it will select everything from the `blogs` table.
It's then going to query the `products` table, using an `inner join`, to select products that have a corresponding blog entry.
The second part of the `where` clause is going to just get the specific character. The `?` is because `category_id` can be any integer.

Comment: The result is coming but its not filtering for category id=1. Instead its showing where category id=2 also.

Comment: this query should show all blogs but when it has category with id of 1 linked to it it will show it nested . but overall it will return all blogs even with category 2

Comment: its eager loading relations its not filtering backwards , it only filtering through the nested queries

Comment: @HijenHEK Good spot, I was typing without checking the code. I've updated my answer now that will fix this issue.

Comment: @JustCarty as far as i understood the relations , your query will always return all the blogs regardless of the category_id ,, he asking for the blogs related to the category_id = 1 , and you are giving him all the blogs and eager load catories if they have id=1 

//// example : users have posts posts has tags , give the users with posts that has tags = 1 , you query will return all users and tags eager loaded with them null if they dont have id=1 and one item if they do

Comment: @HijenHEK You're right - again! I've come up with another solution and I believe this one will work. I was overcomplicating things, because I wasn't sure what OP wanted!

Comment: @JustCarty one of us does not understand how eager loading works , can you check my answer and give me some thought coz i am pretty sure thats how you do it .

Comment: @HijenHEK I have edited my answer, I hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: @JustCarty yes, glad you did , here you said with is optional , so using eager loading make no sense , can you please confirm that my code does exactly the same thing ? i am literally lost here if he wants it using subqueries thats fine i am just curious of what you think of the answer i gave .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232416/discussion-between-justcarty-and-hijenhek).

Answer (score 0):

1. Catory with id 1
2. fetch its products
3. fetch blogs for each of its products ( map over products )
4. flatten the results ( since its gonna be nested for each product )

```
   Category::find(1)->products->map->blogs->flatten();
```

you can use Tinker to interact with you application's query builder and eloquent models from terminal you can use :

```
    $ php artisan tinker
```

For more clause you can use collection methods :

```
   Category::find(1)->products->map->blogs->flatten()->where('status', 'Y')
        ->where('featured_position', 'Y')
        ->sortDesc('id') ;
```